# Manipulating the Toolbar's title and other elements

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm using the AppCompat toolbar, and for the most part its great. However, dealing with the title has been a nightmare. It's set to the app name by default, and I cannot find a way to hide it.

I was trying to hide it so that I can add my own textview so that I could properly align the title text to the top currently its left-aligned but vertically centered. I could not figure out how to position it where it would be normally if I didn't make my toolbar height longer than usual.

How have you guys been managing the toolbar? How can I align the title text to be at the top position where the title's normally are?

Edit: I've added a screenshot of what it looks like. I'm trying to keep my project private for now so I erased any identifying elements. But notice that the D (which is the title) is not aligned to the top.

[image: toolbar]

Comment: Are you setting your toolbar as support actionbar."setSupportActionBar(toolbar);"?

Comment: Yes I've set all the necessary settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have set your toolbar as  action bar `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
then you can sipmly disable the title by using

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and add a textview as your Title in your toolbar layout as toolbar is also a view. See following

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/material_blue"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarCustomIconColor" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
```

This way you can arrange your title anywhere and customize accordingly.

Comment: That seems to be the setting I was looking for, let me give it a try!

Comment: @Doronz yeah.Try this and do accept the answer if it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

to change Toolbar title try this

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Text");
```

for custom layout for Toolbar try this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar); //replace with your custom toolbar title
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using ToolBar from support v7 AppCompat 
after that set that toolbar as action bar and then set action bar title for simple title or you want to set your custom layout inside toolbar then same as we are doing in action bar hence.. now your toolbar work as a actionbar..

See below example from ActionBarActivity..

```
 mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Now if you do anything with action bar related methods it is ultimately affected in ToolBar.